# Passing static JSON to Django Template - best practices?

Tags: python, django, json

I have a JSON data file that is part of my application (version controlled, etc.), and several of our templates need the data in this file to render properly.

**What are the pros and cons of various ways of making this JSON data available to the templates?**

Let's start with the fairly simple option of storing the JSON data as a template, asking the template renderer to generate it, parsing that as JSON, and passing that as a template context param for each view that needs it:

```
'mydata': simplejson.loads(render_to_string('data/mydata.json'))
```

(This seems somewhat wasteful of CPU cycles and possibly disk access.  Would the rendered JSON "template" at least be cached automatically?)

What are some other options?  Is there any built-in feature of Django I'm missing that's designed for this type of use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and probably fastest thing to do is to just parse the json in your views.py outside of the actual view:

```
mydata = simplejson.loads(json_file)

def foo(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'template.html', {"mydata": mydata},
        content_type="application/xhtml+xml")
```

The json will only be parsed the first time a view from the views.py file is requested, subsequent requests will not cause it to be parsed again. You could alternately use a context processor, as suggested.

Comment: The simplest ideas are often the best ones and most easily overlooked :)

Comment: @dkamins: do note that this has the downside of slowing down your startup slightly. Since it's loaded immediately when loading the view, it would slow down the first view of other views in that module too

Comment: @WoLpH No, it'll only slow down the first request of the first view from the module, and even then it'll only slow it down microseconds, and the first request will be marginally slower because the module has to be imported anyways.

Comment: @zeekay: that's what I said: "The first view of other views in that module". I don't see how you can estimate that it will "only slow it down microseconds" without knowing how much data dkamins is talking about though. Care to elaborate on that?

Comment: @WoLpH In my answer I specified it would be parsed the first time a view in the views.py was requested. I took your comment "it would slow down the first view of other views in that module too" to mean that every view in the views.py would incur consecutive penaltyies on *their* first request. I guess we meant the same thing? As for the time it would take to parse the JSON, I'm making the assumption the JSON is fairly small, it's true. On my system parsing a 10kb JSON file takes less than 100 usec.

Comment: @zeekay: it seems I have read over that part, my apologies. Agreed if it's a 10kb json file, it will be negligible in that case. With a large file it would be noticable.

Answer (score 1):

If the data should be available on many/all pages, than a `context_processor` might be your best solution: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

If you only need it on a couple of specific pages, than you can simply pass it to the template like you are doing now or make a template tag out of it.

As for saving cpu time, if you store it in a threadlocal variable than you don't have to parse it every time.

Comment: @dkamins: you can find an example here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/302088-thread-local-storage-in-python-24/

Basically you make a variable like this: `var = threading.local()` and then you get the variable if available, or set it if not.