# How to pass static js file in django template script?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I want to load the staticfile json that is present in the code into the js to host the swagger.

My index.html:

```
<HTML>
<head>
{% load static %}
</head>
<body>
<script src="{% static "js/script1" %}"></script>
<script>
var json_contents = // Use the static json `js/json1.json` in here?
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to do the above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using JSON in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286192/using-json-in-django-template)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234242/passing-static-json-to-django-template-best-practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelled the `static` template tag

```
{% load static %} <!-- not "staticfiles" -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <body>
  <script src="{% static "js/script1.js" %}"></script> <!-- missed .js extention -->
  <script>

    async function load() {
        let url = '{% static "js/json1.json" %}';
        let json_contents = await (await fetch(url)).json();
        console.log(json_contents);
    }
    load();

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Documentation: Configuring static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)

Comment: Got it. But the question I am asking is not that. It is how to include the static json1.json inside the script. Though, I will make the change in the question

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: No. I am currently using vanilla javascript.

Comment: is this JSON file is residing in the local server or external server?

Comment: it is present in the static folder

Comment: Actually, it did. Thanks